# Cheese launches but webcam area is black

Tags: webcam, cheese

**Command-line 12.04 Cheese**

`(cheese:4144): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to add a widget with type GtkImage to a GtkToggleButton, but as a GtkBin subclass a GtkToggleButton can only contain one widget at a time; it already contains a widget of type GtkLabel`

Is there a fix so that Cheese will work in Ubuntu 12.04?  The program comes up but the webcam area is black.

I am running Unity 2D on a T42 Thinkpad.

All programs similar to Cheese recognize my webcam as does Skype, but I really like Cheese and the error message may be ominous for other software failures.

Answer (score 0):

in cheese settings , change resolution to lower one and try again